# Avoid casting using polymorphism (or design patterns)

Tags: kotlin, design-patterns

I have the following classes:

```
interface Event

interface NotificationEvent : Event

data class InviteEvent(val userId: Long, val inviteeId: Long) : NotificationEvent
```

`Event` represents a generic event
`NotificationEvent` represents an event that trigger a notification
`InviteEvent` represents an implementation of `NotificationEvent`

I would write a code that *reacts* to notification events, writing handlers for every type of event.
Accordingly to "Open-close" principle, I'd like to avoid to edit some existing classes to handle new types of event (i.e. avoid the hell switch case).
The idea that I came up with was creating the following classes:

```
abstract class NotificationEventHandler<T : NotificationEvent> {
    fun handle(notificationEvent: NotificationEvent) {
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        if (isSupported(notificationEvent)) {
            handleInternal(notificationEvent as T)
        }
    }

    protected abstract fun isSupported(notificationEvent: NotificationEvent): Boolean
    protected abstract fun handleInternal(notificationEvent: T)
}

@Component
class InviteEventHandler : NotificationEventHandler<InviteEvent>() {

    override fun isSupported(notificationEvent: NotificationEvent) =
        notificationEvent is InviteEvent

    override fun handleInternal(notificationEvent: InviteEvent) {
        // Logic here
    }

}
```

The idea is that, in my service I can autowire all my `NotificationHandler` classes, call `handle` on each one, and the internal logic will call `handleInternal` if necessary.

```
@Service
@Transactional
class NotificationServiceImpl(
    val notificationEventHandlers: List<NotificationEventHandler<*>>
) : NotificationService {
    override fun onNotificationEvent(notificationEvent: NotificationEvent) {
        notificationEventHandlers.forEach {
            it.handle(notificationEvent)
        }
    }
```

I really do not like this implementation... when I see casting in my code, normally I'm doing something wrong (i.e. missing some design pattern or ignoring polymorphism powers).
Moreover I'm invoking `handle` on every handler instead of calling it only on supported ones.

Do you have some idea how to implement this without casting?

Thank you so much.
Francesco

Comment: I suggest eliminating the `Event` interfaces. If different types of events require different logic, there is no advantage to abstracting all events the same way.

Comment: I need `Event` and `NotificationEvent` because in my `EventBus` I route them differently

Comment: Routing events based on type is the root cause of the need for casting. Casting is the price paid for the design of the event bus.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if that's what you're looking for but it will avoid unchecked casts.

Instead of only checking if the event is of the right type (`notificationEvent is InviteEvent`), you can try safe cast, changing isSupported to return T? and not a boolean, then in the actual implementation you can use event as? InviteEvent or whatever.

If the result is not null, then you can safely call handleInternal with it.

```
abstract class NotificationEventHandler<T : NotificationEvent> {

    fun handle(notificationEvent: NotificationEvent){
        castIfSupported(notificationEvent)?.let(this::handleInternal)
    }

    protected abstract fun handleInternal(notificationEvent: T)
    protected abstract fun castIfSupported(event: NotificationEvent): T?
}

class InviteEventHandler : NotificationEventHandler<InviteEvent>() {
    override fun handleInternal(notificationEvent: InviteEvent) {
        println("this is an invite")
    }
    override fun castIfSupported(event: NotificationEvent): InviteEvent? {
        return event as? InviteEvent
    }
}
```

Comment: This could be an option... but there is not a way to avoid cast completely?
As I said in my question, using polymorphism or some design patterns?

Comment: As long as you're using a list with wildcards in your service, i don't think it is possible to avoid casts completely

Comment: The list with wildcards is the solution I came up with. Maybe there is a straightforward/different approach

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Visitor pattern should help, which you can find [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) or [here](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor). It can be used to work with objects on the same hierarchy. New object can be added with minimal modification (no casting). The down side of this pattern is the Visitor class (which is `EventHandler` below) must implement the `process()` method for all possible Event types. This is also the place you change when adding new event type. I am not familiar with Kotlin, the following is pseudo-code only:

```
class Event {
    abstract process(EventHandler handler);
}

class NotificationEvent : Event {
    process(EventHandler handler);
}

class InviteEvent : NotificationEvent {
    process(EventHandler handler) {
        handler.handle(this)
    }
}

class ImportantEvent : NotificationEvent {
    process(EventHandler handler) {
        handler.handle(this)
    }
}

class EventHandler {

    process(InviteEvent event) {
        ...
    }


    process(ImportantEvent event) {
        ...
    }
}

class CustomEventHandler : EventHandler {

    process(ImportantEvent event) {
        // customer processing
    }
}

// run-time

EventHandler handler = new EventHandler();
EventHandler customHandler = new CustomEventHandler();
Event event = retrieveEvent(...)
Event importantEvent = retrieveImportantEvent(...)

event.process(handler);
importantEvent.process(handler); // default processing
importantEvent.process(customHandler); // custom processing
```